# Cant center vertical layout

Tags: java, alignment, vaadin

I've been trying to center my layout but it only centers a little bitfor some reason (about 1cm maybe). Here's my code:

```
VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
VerticalLayout buttons = new VerticalLayout(lHeader, merchantSearch, addMerchant, showMerchants);

public MainMenuView() {
    vLayout.setSizeFull();
    vLayout.addComponent(buttons);
    vLayout.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    this.setCompositionRoot(vLayout);

    addMerchant.setStyleName("mystyle");
    showMerchants.setStyleName("mystyle");
    merchantSearch.setStyleName("mystyle");
    lHeader.addStyleName("mylabelstyle");
    addMerchant.addClickListener(e -> addMerchant());
    showMerchants.addClickListener(e -> showMerchants());
    merchantSearch.addClickListener(e -> merchantSearch());

}
```

Comment: What version of Vaadin are you using? Have you tried to use `setComponentAlignment()` on `buttons` instead of `vLayout`? (I think you'll need to do it for all 4 subcomponents of `buttons`.) If that is not what you need, then please explain more detailed what you want to do and what you currently have.

Comment: Are you sure that the buttons layout is not centered? Maybe the content of the button layout is not centered at all. Where are you aligning and sizing the content of the button layout?

Comment: @Cashbee yes this worked, had to centre each button individually thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
VerticalLayout buttons = new VerticalLayout();

public MainMenuView() {

    buttons.addComponents(lHeader, merchantSearch, addMerchant, showMerchants);
    buttons.setComponentAlignment(lHeader, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    buttons.setComponentAlignment(merchantSearch, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    buttons.setComponentAlignment(addMerchant, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    buttons.setComponentAlignment(showMerchants, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

    vLayout.setSizeFull();
    vLayout.addComponent(buttons);
    vLayout.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    this.setCompositionRoot(vLayout);

    addMerchant.setStyleName("mystyle");
    showMerchants.setStyleName("mystyle");
    merchantSearch.setStyleName("mystyle");
    lHeader.addStyleName("mylabelstyle");
    addMerchant.addClickListener(e -> addMerchant());
    showMerchants.addClickListener(e -> showMerchants());
    merchantSearch.addClickListener(e -> merchantSearch());

}
```